# Where does Bluestacks store apk files for installed apps?

Tags: apk, bluestacks

On your PC how can you find the apk files that you install in BlueStacks? Someone suggested to go to C:\ProgramData\BlueStacks_bgp64\Engine\Android and check the .vdi files there with 7z. I did so, but I did not find anything in root.vdi. The system folders and files are there but no sign of installed apps. Data_0.vdi is a large file, I think the virtual system might be in that one, but if I open it in 7z, I can only see a large image file in it. It is 65GB in size, in spite of that I have no games and apps installed in Bluestacks, only Messenger. Should I mount that and browse it for the apks, or it is useless effort?

Answer (score 4):

[@Bencuri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11058342/bencuri) your are very near to solution. Just follow this steps to get apk files. Before the you need `7-zip` software which is free.

1. Locate the folder `C:\ProgramData\BlueStacks_nxt\Engine\` or bluestack engine folder which depends upon version of bluestacks
2. Locate your instance. For eg: my instance name is `Nougat64` and it location will be `C:\ProgramData\BlueStacks_nxt\Engine\Nougat64`.
   [image]
3. Here you will find a file name `Data.vhd` and you have to open it with 7zip.
4. In 7Zip go to app folder and here you will find all installed apps.
   [image]

For eg: Here I want to locate instagram apk file then go to com.instagram.*
[image]